# Evaluating the following sums with these suppositions. I really need help with this.

Tags: summation

I have tried everything and I am just unable to solve the following sums. Mainly because I do not understand the suppositions and why they are there in the first place and further I do not get what the term a with a subscripted i or an expression with j is supposed to denote. I was able to do all other sums except the ones with aforementioned characteristics.

I really need a straightforward explanation/answer to this, thanks in advance.

Suppositions:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_{i}=19\;$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^{20}a_{i}=-5\;.$$

These are the sums:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}(9-a_{i})\;$$
$$\sum_{j=4}^{13}(a_{j-3}+a_{j+7})\;$$
$$\sum_{i=11}^{21}(4a_{i}-4)\;$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{21}(a_{k-1}-a_{ \lfloor k/2 \rfloor})\;$$ 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{1}\;\sum_{j=1}^{5}(4+a_{5i+j})\;$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}(a_{2i})+\sum_{i=1}^{10}(a_{2i-1}-6)\;$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}(i+a_{i})\;$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_{i}=19\;$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^{20}a_{i}=-5\;$$
 $$\sum_{i=1}^{20}a_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_{i}+\sum_{i=11}^{20}a_{i}=-5\;$$

$$19+\sum_{i=11}^{20}a_{i}=-5\;$$ we get
$$\sum_{i=11}^{20}a_{i}=-5-19=-24\;$$ 
now you want 
(I) $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}(9-a_{i})\;$$
 $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}9-\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_{i}=9*10-19=71\;$$

(II)$$\sum_{j=4}^{13}(a_{j-3}+a_{j+7})=(a_{1}+a_{11})+(a_{2}+a_{12})+(a_{3}+a_{13})+.....+(a_{10}+a_{20})\;$$
$$\sum_{j=4}^{13}(a_{j-3}+a_{j+7})=a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+...+a_{19}+a_{20}= \sum_{i=1}^{20}a_{i}=-5\;$$

(III)
$$\sum_{i=0}^{1}\;\sum_{j=1}^{5}(4+a_{5i+j})=\sum_{j=1}^{5}(4+a_{j})+\sum_{j=1}^{5}(4+a_{5+j})=2*\sum_{j=1}^{5}4+\sum_{j=1}^{5}(a_{j})+\sum_{j=1}^{5}(a_{5+j})=59\;$$
because
$$\sum_{j=1}^{5}(a_{j})+\sum_{j=1}^{5}(a_{5+j})=(a_{1})+...+(a_{5})+(a_{6})+...(a_{10})=\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_{i}=19$$

now you can do the rest

Comment: I am having trouble with 4, 5 and 6. I still haven't been able to solve those.

Comment: for $\frac{k}{2}$ put even values and try to sum them

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to think about what terms are being summed in each one.  For the first, you have $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}9-a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{10}9 - \sum_{i=1}^{10}a_i$$
The second you are given and the first you should be able to evaluate.  The point is to test your understanding of the summation notation.  One of them cannot be evaluated with what you have.